# React Context with Multiple State Values not updating initial values

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-state

I am building a generic form context to help manage state of my forms.  While everything is working, I cannot get my Errors object to initial set on my form.  It looks like only  one state is being set, not both.  From other components I have used, I am not aware there can only be one useState in a functional component?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const FormContext = React.createContext();

// sample initialErrors looks like {password: "Error"}

const ZForm = ({ children, initialValues, initialErrors }) => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialErrors);  // sets as expected.
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialValues);  // initial values not set.

  console.log("ZForm Intial Err:", initialErrors);
  console.log("ZForm State Err:", errors); // always null!

  const handleFormChange = (event, validators) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <FormContext.Provider
        value={{
          form,
          errors,
          handleFormChange,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </FormContext.Provider>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ZForm;
```

My Login component initiates this form to test

```
function Login() {
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  function handleLogin({ email, password }) {
    setError({ password: "test" }); // simulate an error
  }

  console.log("Login Erros", error); // confirms error is set on submit.
  return (
    <div className="page" style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <div className="inlineForm">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <ZForm
          initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
          initialErrors={error}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={4}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
              <ZTextField label="Email" name="email"></ZTextField>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
              <ZTextField label="Password" name="password"></ZTextField>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <FormActionButtons
              onSave={handleLogin}
              //         disabled={isLoading}
            ></FormActionButtons>
          </Grid>
        </ZForm>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Can you add reproducible example? You are giving mixed messages in your comments. You say error is defined and just below you say it is null?

Comment: Code sample:  https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-firefly-i64zf?file=/src/ZForm.js      if you move the useState(initialErrors) to the top of that file, you'll see the error but lose the form values.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it looks like you are passing nothing to your ```ZForm``` component ```initialErrors``` prop. ```initialErrors``` is equal to ```error``` but ```error``` is initialized inside of ```Login.js``` with ```useState()``` without a default value. The value of ```error``` in ```Login.js``` only gets updated when ```handleLogin()``` is called. So the initial state for ```ZForm``` will be nothing or ```undefined```, because that's the value of ```initialState``` when the ```ZForm``` component is first rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The `initialState` of your `ZForm` component is empty, because you are passing in nothing to the `initialErrors` prop. As opposed to the `initialValues` prop which is getting an object.

`error` in this component:

```
<ZForm
  initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
  initialErrors={error}
>
```

is defined as nothing here in this line:

```
const [error, setError] = useState();
```

`useState(initialErrors)` only uses `initialErrors` once, when the component renders. Changing the value any time after the component has rendered will not effect the state. At the time the component renders, `initialErrors` with be equal to the value of `error` passed in to `ZForm`, which is nothing or `undefined`.

If you change `useState` in `Login.js` to this:

```
const [error, setError] = useState({password: "test"});
```

You will now see `{password: "test"}` set in the initial state of `ZForm`.

If you want to be able share the errors between `Login.js` and `ZForm`, you should remove the `useState` for errors from `ZForm`, this line:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialErrors);
```

And instead, call the `initialErrors` prop on the `ZForm` component in `Login.js` simply `errors`, and use that value in your component.

`Login.js`:

```
<ZForm
  initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
  errors={errors}
>
```

`ZForm.js`:

```
const ZForm = ({ children, initialValues, errors }) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial means "first" in this context. It's assigned to that value on the very first call, and **ignored forever** after that, whether it changes or not. Consider:

```js
const [number] = useState(Math.random());
```

The value of `number` will never change, as it only considers the argument once.

In your case, you have 2 different, distinct places where `errors` is stored: one in `Login`, and another in `ZForm`. The linting error in your sandbox shows the `setErrors` function in `ZForm` being unused, and that function is the only way to update the value in `ZForm`.

In short, you should pick one or the other to be the source of record:

---

Using the `errors` in `Login`, `ZForm` would simply accept the errors as an argument and pass it down:

```js
const ZForm = ({ children, initialValues, errors }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialValues);
  console.log("ZForm State Err:", errors); // whatever is passed in

  // ...
```

---

Storing errors in `ZForm` is a little tricker, because to use it within `Login`, the form would have to wrap **around** the `Login` component, rather than being nested in it.
If you want to use the one in `ZForm`, you would have to add `setErrors` to the `FormContext.Provider` value, but note that since `ZForm` is rendered inside of `Login`, you won't be able to refer to it there unless you wrap it in another components, e.g.:

```js
const ZForm = ({ children, initialValues, initialErrors }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialValues); // initial values not set.
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialErrors); // sets as expected.

  console.log("ZForm Intial Err:", initialErrors);
  console.log("ZForm State Err:", errors);

  // NOT SAFE! See comments below
  const handleFormChange = (event, validators) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <FormContext.Provider
        value={{
          form,
          errors,
          setErrors,
          handleFormChange
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </FormContext.Provider>
    </form>
  );
};
```

```js
function Login() {
  // use the `setErrors` from `ZForm`'s context
  const { errors, setErrors } = useContext(FormContext);

  function handleLogin({ email, password }) {
    setErrors((errors) => ({
      ...errors,
      password: "test",
    })); // simulate an error
  }

  return (
    <div className="page" style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <div className="inlineForm">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        {/* form content goes here... */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Wrap `ZForm` around the `Login` form:
export default () => (
  <ZForm initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}>
    <Login />
  </ZForm>
);
```

---

Forms in React are tricky. They just don't tend to fit as well into the top down model of React. There are also subtle bugs like your `handleFormChange`, which should use a function argument to `setForm` rather than referencing `form` directly (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). I highly recommend using a library for this rather than rolling your own. There are many others, but one I've found to be relatively intuitive is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form